# React-three-fiber extrudeBufferGeometry not affected by lights

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber

Look at this https://codesandbox.io/s/geometry-2d-forked-2qxuh?file=/src/index.js:645-666 there is a cube made by `<boxBufferGeometry />`, extruded triangle made by `<extrudeBufferGeometry />` and `<pointLight />` which should cause different color for each side of each geometry. This principle works for the cube but it looks like the `<pointLight />` has no effect on extruded triangle, extruded triangle has all sides covered by one color despite there is `<pointLight />` which should make the edges of the extruded triangle visible but for some reason it doesn't. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: `MeshBasicMaterial` does not respond to lights.

Comment: @WestLangley Thank you very much! Problem solved. I didn't know about this difference between `MeshStandardMaterial` and `MeshBasicMaterial`. I'm still kinda new to three.js.